# When to use alternating series test or the ratio test.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { (-4)^ n }{ 3^{2n+2} }  } $$

I am confused whether to use alternating series test or the ratio test.

When I used ratio test then it converges. My doubt is that since the series alternates, we should use alternating series test .

Comment: You don't need either test. The series is geometric, and can be re-written as $\frac{1}{9} \sum \left( \frac{-4}{9} \right)^n$. Since $\left| \frac{-4}{9} \right| < 1$, the series converges.

Comment: @Nick is right - and, in addition, that allows you to find the sum!

Comment: Use both.  Apart from anything else, it will be good practice.  (But remember that sometimes the answer from a convergence test is "don't know".)

Comment: Actually you can use alternating series test because the summand converges to $0$ decreasingly. I think the 'doubt' of OP isn't whether we **should** use alternating series test, but whether there is a better **test** for the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a bunch of different tests, to get a variety of answers - each of them *correct*, but not necessarily *equally informative*.

In order from worst to best:

---

**The alternating series test**. This says that a series converges if *(**not** only if!)* the terms go to $0$, alternate sign, and have decreasing absolute value. The $n$th term in the series is $$a_n=(-1)^n\cdot ({4\over 9})^n\cdot{1\over 9},$$ so the alternating series test tells us that this converges.

---

**The root test**. While the alternating series test told us that the series converges, it didn't tell us whether it converged *absolutely* or merely *conditionally*. If we apply the root test, we will figure this out: we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{\vert a_n\vert}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{4\over 9}\cdot {1\over\sqrt[n]{9}}=0,$$
 so the series **converges absolutely**.

---

**The ratio test**. We have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n\over a_{n+1}}=-{9\over 4}$, so - just like the root test - the ratio test says that the series **converges absolutely**. Like the root test, this provides more information than the alternating series test (which just said that the series converged).

---

But think about what we just did: the ratio of successive terms doesn't just *approach* $-{9\over 4}$, it *always is* ${9\over 4}$. That is, we're dealing with a **geometric series** whose ratio is $-{4\over 9}$ (which is strictly between $-1$ and $1$). This tells us not only that the series converges absolutely, but $\color{red}{\mbox{the exact value it converges to}}$ - namely, $${a_1\over 1-r}={-{4\over 81}\over {13\over 9}}=-{4\over 117}.$$ **This is the right thing to do in this case**. It gives the most information, and is as easy if not easier than anything else you can do here.

*(Incidentally, the only reason I ranked the ratio test better than the root test is that it points out that the series is geomteric, if one has not already noticed that.)*

Comment: Ohh...  this is so confusing.. I thought whenever there is $(-1)^n$ or something like that, I thought of using alternating series test

Comment: @tienlee Just because you *can* use a given test doesn't mean that you *should*. The alternating series test applies here, but doesn't tell you as much as the ratio or root tests do, and *those* don't tell you as much as recognizing the geometric series does. The alternating series test is limited in terms of the information it can provide: all it can tell you is that the series converges. In this case other techniques provide more information, and so they are preferable. (On the other hand, there are situations where it's pretty ideal - e.g. the alternating harmonic series.)

Answer (score 1):

Use the root or ratio test. Note that the series $\sum ar^n$ converges iff $|r|<1$ so even if $r$ is negative and it alternates the geometric property is so strong that it overrides all other concerns.

Just to be clear this particular series IS geometric so you use the criterion for convergence of a geometric series.

Comment: Why cannot I use alternating series test

Comment: I think you can.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio test is fine, assuming you applied absolute values when using the ratio test, since the ratio test requires the terms to be strictly positive.

This works because absolute convergence implies convergence.

However, as a point of technicality, we have an alternating geometric series here, so if you apply the ratio test with absolute values, you get a geometric series.

> You cannot use the ratio test to prove that a geometric series converges.

This is because the proof of the ratio test requires the fact that a geometric series converges, so we would have a circular argument.

Comment: Why cannot I use alternating series test

Comment: @tienlee The use of the alternating series test is to check if a series is conditionally convergent (it can only prove that). The ratio test is absolute convergence.

Comment: It's not quite true that you can't use the ratio test to prove that a geometric series converges. You can totally do that: you first prove the general theorem for geometric series, then you prove the ratio test, then you apply the ratio test in a specific case ... which *happens* to be a geometric series. That's not circular, just horribly redundant.